# Metric on a graph

Tags: metric-spaces, random-graphs

I know that for a metric space $(X,d)$ we can define a new metric $\text{dist}_{l}$ on $X$, where $\text{dist}_{l}(x,y)$ is the infimum of the lengths of all rectifiable paths joining $x$ to $y$.

On a graph, we can introduce a distance by declaring every edge to be isometric to the unit interval in $\mathbb{R}$.
In this case, instead of taking the infimum of the lengths of the paths, the minimum is taken. Here is my trouble, since I do not understand why the infimum is the same as the minimum in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed taking the infimum, 
$$
d(x,y):=\inf\{|\gamma|: \gamma \text{ connects }x \text{ and } y\}.
$$
but as
$$
A:=\{|\gamma|: \gamma \text{ connects }x \text{ and } y\} \subset \mathbb{N}, 
$$
we have some additional structure due $A$ being a discrete set.

Now, as $d(x,y)$ is an accumulation point of $A$(this just comes from the definition of infimum), there is a sequence of elements $\{n_k\}_{k} \subset A \subset \mathbb{N}$ with $n_k \longrightarrow d(x,y)$. 
However, a sequence of natural number can only converge if it is eventually constant, that is $\exists K \in \mathbb{N} $ such that for all $k \ge K$, $n_k = d(x,y)$.

As $n_K \in A$, there is a path $\gamma^\prime$ connecting $x$ to $y$ such that $|\gamma^\prime|=n_K = d(x,y)$. That is, the infimum is in fact achieved. Therefore, you can take the minimum in the definition.

Comment: But if you take two points on the interiors of the edges of the graph, you cannot assume that the length of the paths is a natural number, no?

Comment: Oh, I was assuming that you were only talking about distances between vertices. Well, in that case, suppose that $x \in [e_1,e_2]$ and $y \in [e^\prime_1,e^\prime_2]$. Get the paths $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3$ and $\gamma_4$ minimizing the distances between $e_1$ and $e^\prime_1$, $e_1$ and $e^\prime_2$, $e_2$ and $e^\prime_1$ and $e_2$ and $e^\prime_2$ respectively. Now to go from $x$ to $y$, you will either go from $x$ to $e_1$ or $e_2$, then to either $e^\prime_1$ or $e^\prime_2$. Now, you reduced your problem to four possible cases. Take the minimum between then.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have understood it perfectly!